# Android : Run Card View and Recycler view in lower version

Tags: android

I am new in Android Studio. I just Develop an application for **Card View** , its working in Android L. But it is not working in lower version.

When I try to execute in lower version getting an error

**Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]**

Can any one please tell me what to do for run this application in Lower version

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
}
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
repositories {
jcenter()
}
dependencies {
compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.2"
}

List<String> dirs = [
'main',     
'common',  
'template'] process
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 21
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        dirs.each { dir ->
            java.srcDirs "src/${dir}/java"
            res.srcDirs "src/${dir}/res"
        }
    }
    androidTest.setRoot('tests')
    androidTest.java.srcDirs = ['tests/src']
     }
    }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.cardview"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"
          android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".CardViewActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your device tell you that its API level is too low.**

Let's take a look at your building configuration:

Your *AndroidManifest.xml* file specifies:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"
          android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

Your Gradle build file specifies:

```
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 21
```

**This is contradictory.**

You should use:

```
minSdkVersion 7
targetSdkVersion 21
```

(And actually you could get rid off the *AndroidManifest.xml* `uses-sdk` directive.)